# Kendo UI for Angular Spreadsheet

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Do you know if there is a time-frame for converting the Kendo UI Spreadsheet into a Kendo UI for Angular widget?

If not, do you have any controls that could be used to display xlsx files? Is there an example, maybe, of converting this type of file into the correct format needed for the grid? I have seen a couple csv-to-json converters, but would like to know if you have a recommended approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know plan is to build Spreadsheet for Kendo UI for Angular, but currently there is no time-frame. Surely not until May, and I am guessing here, but I would say this year definitely not.

If you need it, you can use Spreadsheet from Kendo UI for jQuery. Mixing those component is more or less officially supported. Check [this link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/framework/kendo-jquery/).

I suppose converting xlsx to json heavily depends on you back-end. If you have for example ASP.NET Core you can found plenty examples online.

Comment: There's a problem when using the jQuery version in Angular, it throws an exception when the component destroys, even when executing `this.spreadsheet.destroy();` and `kendo.jQuery(this.spreadsheetElement.nativeElement).remove();` as recommended by Progress/Telerik. As a result, when opening a new page the old one is appended.